# Customize "the_posts_pagination" and put list instead div

Tags: functions, hooks, pagination, twitter-bootstrap

**Hello everybody**, I need help with my custom wordpress pagination.

I'm looking to get this :

[image]

This is what I did :

in the functions.php, I've add this code :

```
function wp_custom_pagination($args = [], $class = 'pagination') {
    if ($GLOBALS['wp_query']->max_num_pages <= 1) return;

    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, [
            'mid_size'                   => 2,
            'prev_next'                  => false,
            'prev_text'                  => __('Older posts', 'textdomain'),
            'next_text'                  => __('Newer posts', 'textdomain'),
            'screen_reader_text' => __('Posts navigation', 'textdomain'),
    ]);

    $links       = paginate_links($args);
    $next_link = get_previous_posts_link($args['next_text']);
    $prev_link = get_next_posts_link($args['prev_text']);
    $template    = apply_filters( 'navigation_markup_template', '
    <div class="col-auto">
        <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-white text-dark">%3$s</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto">
        <nav class="navigation %1$s" role="navigation">
                <h2 class="screen-reader-text">%2$s</h2>
                <ul class="nav-links pagination mb-0 text-dark">
                    <li class="page-item">%4$s</li>
                </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto">
        <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-white text-dark">%5$s</a>
    </div>', $args, $class);

    echo sprintf($template, $class, $args['screen_reader_text'], $prev_link, $links, $next_link);}
```

After, I've add this code in my home.php

```
<?php wp_custom_pagination(); ?>
```

But, the result is really not what I want!

Here is the html structure code that I would need for this wp_custom_pagination :

```
            <div class="row justify-content-between align-items-center">
              <div class="col-auto">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-white text-dark">Previous</a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-auto">
                <nav>
                  <ul class="pagination mb-0 text-dark">
                    <li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
                    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
                    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </nav>
              </div>
              <div class="col-auto">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-white text-dark">Next</a>
              </div>
            </div>
```

If anyone could help me and tell me and show me my mistakes and how to get what I want please.

Thanks a lot

---

At this time, this is the result that I obtain :

[image]

This is the generated code of my custom pagination page :

```
<div class="row justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <div class="col-auto">
        <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-white text-dark"></a>
        <a href="http://192.168.1.87/wordpress/blog/page/2">Older posts</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto">
        <nav class="navigation pagination" role="navigation">
            <h2 class="screen-reader-text">Posts navigation</h2>
            <ul class="nav-links pagination mb-0 text-dark">
                <li class="page-item">
                    <span aria-current="page" class="page-numbers current">1</span>
                    <a class="page-numbers" href="http://192.168.1.87/wordpress/blog/page/2">2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto">
        <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-white text-dark"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, if you give a look at the result :

1 - You will see that the *first link (Older post = %3$s)* need to be enclosed with the good css class!

2 - And you'll see that the *"1, 2, 3" links* need to be inside each one "li" not inside one "li"

Comment: Actually, my first issue is to be able to obtain the link of "prev" and "next" to be able to place them in my <a href=""> tags

Comment: Is pagination code logic not working or is the look and feel of pagination design not coming up the way you want?

Comment: HI @Awais , no, actually, the look and feel of pagination design not coming up the way that I want ! I just have edited my post and I've add the result code and result image so you can see the real result of my custom pagination code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making your Custom Pagination design In Demo According Your Need .

below function Replace Your Function:

```
function wp_custom_pagination($args = [], $class = 'pagination') {

if ($GLOBALS['wp_query']->max_num_pages <= 1) return;

$args = wp_parse_args( $args, [
        'mid_size'                   => 2,
        'prev_next'                  => false,
        'prev_text'                  => __('Previous', 'textdomain'),
        'next_text'                  => __('Next', 'textdomain'),
        'screen_reader_text' => __('Posts navigation', 'textdomain'),
]);

$links       = paginate_links($args);
$next_link = get_previous_posts_link($args['next_text']);
$prev_link = get_next_posts_link($args['prev_text']);
$check_prev = (!empty($prev_link))?$prev_link:'Previous';
$check_next = (!empty($next_link))?$next_link:'Next';
$template    = apply_filters( 'navigation_markup_template', '
<div class="container"><div class= "row"><div style="display: flex;justify-content: space-around; align-items: center;" class="paginatin d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"><div class="col-auto">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info" >%3$s</button>
</div>
<div class="col-auto">
    <nav class="navigation %1$s" role="navigation">
            <h2 class="screen-reader-text">%2$s</h2>
            <ul class="pagination mb-0 text-dark">
                <li class="page-item">%4$s</li>
            </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<div class="col-auto">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info">%5$s</button>
</div></div></div><div>', $args, $class);

echo sprintf($template, $class, $args['screen_reader_text'], $check_next, $links, $check_prev);

}
```

Add Some Css In Your Header :

```
function add_css_pagination(){
?>  
    <style type="text/css">
        span.page-numbers.current {
            background: #a8307c;
            color: white;
        }
        button.btn a {
            color: #f4f4f4;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        button.btn.btn-outline-info a {
            color: darkslategrey;
            font-weight: 600;
        }
        button.btn.btn-outline-info {
            background: unset;
            border: 1px solid turquoise;
            color: darkslategrey;
            font-weight: 600;
        }
    </style>

 <?php
 }
 add_action('wp_head','add_css_pagination');
```

Screenshot:[image]

Comment: Can you explain what you've changed please?

Comment: Add some bootstrap class & css and new condition for next prev pagination in custom function

Comment: Thanks! 

It took me a bit of work because I had to modify my css but I admit that it works pretty well!
The only negative point that I don't like too much is the "span + link" enclosed in a single "li" item, I would prefer to enclose it in two separate "li" but hey ...

You have been my only solution for about a month so I give you the +50 bounty

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `the_posts_pagination( wp_custom_pagination () );`, just use this function `paginate_links` and add args as per your requirements.

Sample:

```
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $the_query->max_num_pages,
    'prev_text' => __( 'Previous' ),
    'next_text' => __( 'Next' ),
) );
```

Ref: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/

Comment: Sorry, but your answer does not answer my questions! In addition, what you offer is very simple and it's very basic!

The structure of my pagniation is very complex and my example code above shows what I want to do!

My question was " please tell me and show me my mistakes and how to get what I want please "